What to do with `matplotlib` graphs given in a list that a function returns (or what is an alternative function architecture)?
I have a function that works something like this.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_from_dave(n = 100, r = 10):
    
    my_list = []
    
    for i in range(r):
        
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        x = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
        y = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
        ax.scatter(x, y)
        
        my_list.append((fig, ax))
    
    return(my_list)

The function creates many plots and then saves the figure-axis tuples to a list that is returned.
I now want to access those figures and axes for downstream customization of the plots. However, accessing them has been problematic. For instance, in the below, I get nothing.
np.random.seed(2024)
plot_list = plot_from_dave(10, 3)
plot_list[0]
plt.show()

How can I access these figures and axes to apply further customization outside of the function? Alternatively, how can I set up the function to allow customization of the plots?

You return a list, so you can either index it or loop over it:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_from_dave(n=100, r=10):
    my_list = []

    for i in range(r):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        x = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
        y = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
        ax.scatter(x, y)

        my_list.append((fig, ax))

    return (my_list)


figs = plot_from_dave(r=4)
for i, (fig, ax) in enumerate(figs):
    ax.set_title(f'Title {i+1}')
    # set the color of the dots to a random color
    ax.collections[0].set_facecolor(np.random.rand(3))
    fig.show()

figs[2][1].set_title('Title special 3')
figs[2][1].collections[0].set_facecolor('red')
figs[2][0].show()

This generates 4 plots (and then displays them), giving them different titles and colours after plot_from_dave() completes and returns. It also specifically selects the 3rd one and sets its title and a specific colour and then shows it again.
Note that you don't have to use enumerate() - my example only does so to get a nice index number that can be used to give them the numbered titles. If you don't need something like that, you can of course just for fix, ax in figs:.

I am getting an error: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. Thoughts on a resolution?

Oh, maybe this just a matter of dropping the .show().

Yes, I added the show for anyone trying the example, but your question didn't mention the platform. On Jupyter you probably just evaluate the figure to get it rendered

Weird...it still does not want to show figures in a loop (at least not in Jupyter, where I am most likely to be showing the figures). Calling a particular figure out of the loop works fine, though.

For many notebook setups, the solution is to call .show() but since that doesn't work for you, consider adding the plots as subplots and ending with the resulting combined plot in a code block.
